# Non-existing file/URL returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

Going to `example.com/config` or `example.com/account/login` returns 403 Forbidden.

In reality, `/config` and `/account/login` should be redirected to `index.php` but it gives 403.

My directory structure is like this:

```
/var/www/example
└─/assets
└─/bower_components
└─/node_modules
└─/partials
└─/templates
└─/tests
└─/vendor
└─index.php
```

This is my Virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example

  <DirectoryMatch "^/var/www/example/(?!(assets|partials))\w+">
    Require all denied
  </DirectoryMatch>

  <Location />
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

- I want to disallow access to every folder except `assets` and `partials`, that's why I added that DirectoryMatch directive.
- I use a PHP framework called Slim so I have to add Location and Rewrite directives.

I think Apache thinks my URLs are directories and blocks them. Is there a way to unblock my URLs?

Comment: Do you have an htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
<Directory "/var/www/example">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow From all
</Directory>
```

above the `<DirectoryMatch>` container in your vhost config.

---

Since you're using apache 2.4, then use require all:

```
<Directory "/var/www/example">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: I think I can't use v2.2 directives in v2.4. I used "Require all granted", it's still not working.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I tried adding it above and below the directive.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache 2.4 try to add in the end of your VirtualHost:

```
<Directory /var/www/example>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

# If you want to enable overrides, you should read:
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
Satisfy Any

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```